# How to use q promise in for loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I have a problem when i use q promise in loop. Result show

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> --
>
> --
>
> --

But result that i promise must be:

> 0
>
> --
>
> 1
>
> --
>
> 2
>
> --

There is my code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let row     = planRespone[i];
    let planData    = {
        diary_id:diaryData.id,
        title:row.title
    };
    console.log(i);
    addDiaryPlan(planData)
    .then((insertId) => {
        console.log("--");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
    })
};
```

And support fot it

```
let addDiaryDetail = (data) => {
  let q = Q.defer();
  Mdl.addDiaryDetail(data, function(err, result) {
      if(err) q.reject(err);
      else q.resolve(result);
  });
  return q.promise;
}
```

How can i use promise in this case?

Comment: Use async/await. You may not need Q at all this way. addDiaryDetail could be promisified with util.promisify.

Comment: You can use `each` from async lib, here is documentation: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Comment: @giankotarola - Javascript now has promises built-in and is the future of the Javascript language for managing asynchronous operations.  Much better to teach folks how to use that than the older async library way of doing things.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure! I think you are right but could be an option and the dev has to decide how to do it.

Comment: Use each from the async-q lib which is a promise compatible version of the async lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q

Comment: @giankotarola - I just want to make sure the OP knows about promises and voice an opinion for using the built-in promises instead of a 3rd party library.

Comment: @slebetman - I'm aware of that, but in this case, there is no need for that.  node.js has everything that's needed built right in.

Comment: @jfriend00 But it's a good idea to make the OP aware about async-q anyway because it simplifies a lot of other promise use-cases such as batched parallel requests, conditional loops etc. It also has the nifty feature of being able to pass in an object of promises instead of an array of promises and the result will be wrapped in a similar object. Of course such features are not strictly necessary for this specific question but the OP is using promises so it's good to know about promise-q

Comment: @slebetman - I have no objection to async-q in general.  I use Bluebird for much the same (additional promise mgmt functions not build into the language).  But, it is more important for the OP to know that their problem can be solved easily and entirely with the promise support built right into node.js with no sacrifice.  And, I don't know why you would recommend using `.each()` from that lib instead of `async/await` that is built into the language.  That makes no sense to me.  But, if you think that's a better solution than async/await, then please write your own answer to illustrates.

Comment: Can i use asynce/await instead of q promise, i love this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, I don't see any need for Q at all.  You can do this with node.js built-in functionality (`util.promisify()`).

And when you want to run a `for` loop in sequential order where you wait for an async operation to be done before going to the next iteration of the loop, then `async/await` is the easiest way to do things because it will pause the `for` loop:

```
const util = require('util');
Mdl.addDiaryDetailPromise = util.promisify(Mdl.addDiaryDetail);

async function someFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let row = planRespone[i];
        let planData = {
            diary_id:diaryData.id,
            title:row.title
        };
        console.log(i);
        await Mdl.addDiaryPlanPromise(planData).then(insertId => {
            console.log("--");
        });
    };
}

// usage
someFunction().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This should give you the desired sequence of output.

---

Note, that to use `await`, it has to be inside a function that is declared `async` and that function will always return a promise that resolves when the function is done or rejects when there's some sort of uncaught error in the function (an actual exception or a rejected await).

Comment: Let's me try this way